# I am unable to get bootstrap-select's .selectpicker class to work, any idea why?

Tags: bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

Here is the HTML code I have marked up, but whenever I load the page the select tag does not appear. I believe I have included all of the necessary links, and when I remove the .selectpicker class from the select tag it appears normally, so I must be missing something as to why this does not appear. Thanks!

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>



    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <select class="selectpicker" style="btn-info">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            style: 'btn-info',
            size: 4
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed the "style" attribute of the select tag to "data-style" and still no change.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. could you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the correct CSS and java script libraries-

please check the below code- its working fine, you can add multiple, to let user select multiple values, you can also include a search option, if there is a long list of options try data-live-search-style="startsWith".

please check the code below-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple style="btn-info">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```